# Is Ubuntu Server 18.04 supported on HP ProLiant DL 360p Gen 8

Tags: server, hp, raid, canonical

I'm thinking of purchasing an HP ProLiant DL 360p Gen 8 to run an EVE-NG lab. However I'm unsure if the HP ProLiant DL 360p Gen 8 can run the required OS: Ubuntu Server 18.04. The Ubuntu certified website says Ubuntu Server 18.04 is certified with HP ProLiant DL 360p Gen 10 (not Gen 8). Does anyone know if I'll be able to install this OS on this server?

Comment: We do not provide hardware recommendations.

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of *opinion* based questions.

Answer (score 0):

Load Ubuntu 16.04 first, followed by a release upgrade of Ubuntu 18.04 next.  Tried it out THREE times, and was successful THREE times. Work on DL360 Gen8 servers and earlier.

-rad